DATAPICKER SELECCIONA UNA FECHA ANTERIOR A LA ESCOGIDA
Estoy creando un software para exportar reportes en reactjs, en formato pdf y excel.
para lo cual estoy utilizando un datapicker para agregar la fecha en la que quieres exportar el reporte.
el error que tengo es que al yo seleccionar la fecha en el calenadrio del datapicker me selecciona un dia anterior, por ejemplo si coloco 1 de mayo me muestra 30 de abril.
pero al buscar los datos en la base de datos(mysql) si me muestra el contenido del dia 1 de mayo.
el error solo es en el datapicker.


Deberias agregar tu HTML

No se entiende tu pregunta: Hablas de un datepicker....cual datepicker?? de exportarlo?, tu código dice que conviertes a hora local, pero esa función no hace eso. Favor agregar un [MCVE] y mejorar la explicación
